# Ansible playbook loop with with_items

Tags: linux, ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, sudoers

I have to update `sudoers.d` multiple user files with few lines/commands using `ansible` playbook

**users.yml**

```
user1:
   - Line1111
   - Line2222
   - Line3333

user2:
   - Line4444
   - Line5555
   - Line6666
```

**main.yml**

```
- hosts: "{{ host_group }}"
  vars_files:
    - ../users.yml

  tasks:

       - name: Add user "user1" to sudoers.d
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/sudoers.d/user1
        line: '{{ item }}'
        state: present
        mode: 0440
        create: yes
        validate: 'visudo -cf %s'
      with_items:
          - "{{ user1 }}"
```

The above one is working only for `user1`..

If I want to also include user2 --> How to change the file name : path: `/etc/sudoers.d/user1`

I tried **below and its not working** :

Passing below users as variable to `main.yml` while running

```
users:
   - "user1"
   - "user2"



- name: Add user "{{users}}" to sudoers.d
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/sudoers.d/{{users}}
    line: '{{ item }}'
    state: present
    mode: 0440
    create: yes
    validate: 'visudo -cf %s'
  with_items:
      - "{{ users }}"
```

So, basically I want to pass in users to a variable `{{users}}` as `user1` and `user2` and wanted to use the lines for each user from `users.yml` and add it to respective user files (`/etc/sudoers.d/user1` and `/etc/sudoers.d/user2`).

So `/etc/sudoers.d/user1` should look like

```
Line1111
Line2222
Line3333
```

and `/etc/sudoers.d/user2` should look like

```
Line4444
Line5555
Line6666
```

Comment: I tried the below for users.yml 

~~~users: 
    - user1: 
          - "Line1111" 
          - "Line2222" 
          - "Line3333" 
    - user2: 
          - "Line4444" 
          - "Line5555"

 and also main.yml 

- name: Add user "wasadmin" to sudo avsrelmgmt 
      lineinfile:  ```
        path: /etc/sudoers.d/"{{ users }}"  
        line: '{{ item}}'  
        state: present  
        mode: 0440  
        create: yes  
        validate: 'visudo -cf %s'  
      with_items:  
        - "{{ users }}"~~~

Comment: Could you see the above comment in the answer section below

Answer (score 0):

Try to add quotes:

```
users:
   - "user1"
   - "user2"

- name: "Add user {{users}} to sudoers.d"
  lineinfile:
    path: "/etc/sudoers.d/{{users}}"
    line: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
    mode: 0440
    create: yes
    validate: 'visudo -cf %s'
  with_items:
      - "{{ users }}"
```

As per [Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html) on Using Variables:

> YAML syntax requires that if you start a value with `{{ foo }}` you quote the whole line, since it wants to be sure you aren’t trying to start a YAML dictionary. This is covered on the [YAML Syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#yaml-syntax) documentation.
>
> This won’t work:
>
> ```
> - hosts: app_servers
>   vars:
>       app_path: {{ base_path }}/22
> ```
>
> Do it like this and you’ll be fine:
>
> ```
> - hosts: app_servers
>   vars:
>        app_path: "{{ base_path }}/22"
> ```

Comment: I tried the below for users.yml 

users: 
    - user1: 
          - "Line1111" 
          - "Line2222" 
          - "Line3333" 
    - user2: 
          - "Line4444" 
          - "Line5555"

 and also main.yml 

- name: Add user "wasadmin" to sudo avsrelmgmt  
      lineinfile:  
        path: /etc/sudoers.d/"{{ users }}"  
        line: '{{ item}}'  
        state: present  
        mode: 0440  
        create: yes  
        validate: 'visudo -cf %s'  
      with_items:  
        - "{{ users }}"

Answer (score 0):

```
cat users.yml
---
users:
  - user1:
    filename: user1sudoers
    args:
      - Line1111
      - Line2222
      - Line3333
  - user2:
    filename: user2sudoers
    args:
      - Line4444
      - Line5555
      - Line6666
```

I use template here, instead of lineinfile

```
---
cat sudoers.j2
{% if item.args is defined and item.args %}
{%     for arg in item.args %}
{{ arg }}
{%     endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

the task content

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files: ./users.yml
  tasks:
    - name: sync sudoers.j2 to localhost
      template:
        src: sudoers.j2
        dest: "/tmp/{{ item.filename }}"
      loop: "{{ users_list }}"
      when: "users_list is defined and users_list"
```

after run the task.yml, generate two files under /tmp directory.

```
cat /tmp/user1sudoers
Line1111
Line2222
Line3333

cat /tmp/user2sudoers
Line4444
Line5555
Line6666
```